# Executing ps script on remote machine with VBscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am attempting to execute a powershell script on `10.0.0.20` found at `D:\path\script.ps1` with the parameter of 6.9.0 from `10.0.0.199` using VBscript. I believe I am on the right route with the following code but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

side note, it needs to run as administrator

```
sub main()
    dim strComputer, strUser, strPassword

    strComputer = "10.0.0.20"
    strUser="userName"
    strPassword="password"

    Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer (strComputer, "root\cimv2", strUser, strPassword)
    objSWbemServices.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
end sub
main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable PSRemoting on the remote system and invoke it that way, assuming that your workstation and the remote system are on the same domain, and your domain account has admin access to the remote system.

```
Invoke-Command -computer "10.0.0.20" -scriptblock {. d:\path\script.ps1}
```

Comment: the reason I'm using vbs is because the software calling the script can only call vbs, not powershell. So it needs to be vbs->ps. no ps->ps

Comment: Write your VBScript to execute the Powershell script then. [Example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ilm2/thread/65334d6c-6902-4541-89ce-ffe90b2208d0)